# AWS CloudSearch: different documents in 1 domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm interested in using AWS Cloud Search for my web app. 
I have 3 different document types that I want to make searchable (users - articles - images).

What is the best way to do this with Cloud Search?
Do I need to create 3 different AWS search domains? And does this mean i need to pay for at least 3 search instances?

Or can I put all of them in 1 domain / instance and use something like indexes or types (to use elastic search terminology)?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a better way to solve your problem, I'm looking for a solution too.

Comment: I'm using ec2 hosted elastic search instances

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

1. Add a "searchable_text" index of type text, "category" index of type literal which is faceted enabled.
2. Upload documents of all types with full text search field as "searchable_text" and category as one of "users", "articles" or "images".
3. Query based on `category` to return results from each type.

If your search query is going to be complex with many index fields, you may end up having a lot of null values in many indexed fields if you try to maintain a single domain for different document types. Empty values are not good for indexes and it's better to separate document types into their own domains if you end up there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is exactly because i want to avoid "empty fields" (my documents are all completely different), i was hoping for a better solution... In ElasticSearch, you can group documents in indexes or types, but i don't think it is possible with Cloud Search

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. I guess the fact CloudSearch is still in beta comes into play here. That being said, I feel you should still tick Emil's response as the answer.

Comment: Can someone answer this sub-question: Can you have multiple "search domains" within a single "search instance"? Say I don't have a lot of traffic, I don't think I should need a different virtual machines of each document type...

Comment: @nute , it's not possible to have multiple search domains on the same instance.